# Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm having this error and I can't solve the problem

**VIEW.PY**

```
def projects_add(request, client_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            client = Clients.objects.get(pk=client_id)
            instance.client = client
            instance.created_date = datetime.date.today()
            instance.status = 'Análise'
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request,'Projeto adicionado')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Ocorreu um erro!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects'))
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(client_id)
        all_projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request,'projects.html',{'form':form,
                                            'all_projects':all_projects})
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['owner','farm','warranty','modal','culture','value','final_date']

    def __init__(self, client_id, *args,**kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['value'].required = False
        self.fields['final_date'].required = False
        self.fields['farm'].queryset = Farm.objects.filter(client=client_id)
        self.fields['warranty'].queryset = Farm.objects.filter(client=client_id)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    modal_types = [('CUSTEIO AGRÍCOLA','Custeio Agrícola'),('CUSTEIO PECUÁRIO','Custeio Pecuário'),('INVESTIMENTO AGRÍCOLA','Investimento Agrícola'),('INVESTIMENTO PECUÁRIO','Investimento Pecuário'),('FGPP','FGPP')]
    farm = models.ManyToManyField(Farm, related_name='project_farm',verbose_name='Propriedade beneficiada')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_client',default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Cliente')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_bidder',default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Proponente')
    warranty = models.ManyToManyField(Farm, related_name='project_warranty',default=None, verbose_name='Propriedade de garantia')
    modal = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None,choices=modal_types, null=True, verbose_name='Tipo')
    culture = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, verbose_name='Cultura')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, verbose_name='Status')
    created_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Data de criação')
    value = models.FloatField(max_length=10,null=True, verbose_name='Valor financiado')
    final_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Fim do contrato')
```

**TRACEBACK**

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\luizh\Desktop\Novo Sistema\ATR\projects\views.py", line 30, in projects_add
form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None)
File "C:\Users\luizh\Desktop\Novo Sistema\ATR\projects\forms.py", line 16, in **init**
self.fields['farm'].queryset = Farm.objects.filter(client=client_id)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 974, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 992, in _filter_or_exclude
clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 999, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1375, in add_q
clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1396, in *add_q
child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1329, in build_filter
condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1180, in build_lookup
lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in **init**
self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 120, in get_prep_lookup
self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
File "C:\Users\luizh\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init**.py", line 1824, in get_prep_value
raise e.**class**(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ha7mOkHl8SkjuKDx06TipoflYdFFEdZFxT3ST5DdVZYRSGkHSffTOTGWdDXWaWf1'], 'owner': ['1'], 'farm': ['4'], 'warranty': ['4'], 'modal': ['CUSTEIO AGRÍCOLA'], 'culture': ['toamte'], 'value': [''], 'final_date': ['']}>.
[23/Feb/2022 11:20:44] "POST /projetos/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 135681

I think the problem occurs because of the way I use to define queryset, but I've tried everything and it doesn't work.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

You made `client_id` the first parameter of your `ProjectForm` constructor, so you should create the `ProjectForm` with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def projects_add(request, client_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(client_id, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            client = get_object_or_404(Clients, pk=client_id)
            form.instance.client = client
            form.instance.created_date = datetime.date.today()
            form.instance.status = 'Análise'
            form.save()
            return redirect('projects')
            messages.success(request,'Projeto adicionado')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Ocorreu um erro!')
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(client_id)
    all_projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request,'projects.html',{'form':form, 'all_projects':all_projects})
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: Thanks man! This solved the problem. And thanks for the tip too